# Methods inside of functional components

Tags: react-native, jsx

I'm experiencing a strange issue where the onPress function of a functional child component is triggered whenever the component is rendered.

Relevant parent code which renders the child component from a list of dates. I was also having issues with array.map if the component was a class component, but that's a separate issue.

```
return list_items.map(data => 
  <ChildComponent 
    key={data.day}
    props={data}
  />);
```

And the child component:

```
const ChildComponent = ({ props }) => {
  let date = props.date;
  const someFunction = () => {
    console.log(date)
  }
return (
  <Text><Icon name="angle-right" onPress={someFunction()}/></Text>
)
```

And what I get from the console upon rendering the relevant scene:

> 2018-11-11
>
> 2018-11-12
>
> 2018-11-13
>
> 2018-11-14
>
> 2018-11-15
>
> 2018-11-16

Pressing the icon does nothing, yet it seems to run the function as if it was a lifecycle component. I've also moved the function into the parent component and passed it to the child as recommended per Guruparan Giritharan, and it still executes on render.

```
return list_items.map(data => 
  <ChildComponent 
    key={data.day}
    props={data}
    someFunction={this.someFunction} // function now within parent component
  />);
```

And the updated child:

```
const ChildComponent = ({ props, someFunction }) => {
  return (
    <Text>
      <Icon name="angle-right" onPress={someFunction(props.date)}/> 
    </Text>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
<Text><Icon name="angle-right" onPress={someFunction}/></Text>
```

You are calling the function there itself instead of passing the reference. So the function is called inside each render instead of onPress.

Comment: I changed it so that the function exists inside of the parent component and is being called by the child component, yet no change.

Comment: Do you pass the function of parent component as a prop ?, do you get the console log when you press the icon ?

Comment: I passed the function down from the parent. Pressing the icon doesn't trigger the function, only on render.

Comment: Sometimes it even executes the function 2-3 times per child prop rendered, so I really don't know what's going on.

Comment: you are calling the function on render onPress={someFunction(props.date)} thats the problem it should be a reference onPress={this.props.someFunction}

Comment: Not sure I understand - are you saying that the params should be passed to the function inside of the parent component? I'm passing it as a separate param because the "props" param is data from the array.map function. I updated my example.

Comment: if you need to use someFunction in your onPress along with date the way will be  <Icon name="angle-right" onPress={()=>someFunction(props.date)}/>

Comment: I changed it back to a class-based component and it worked.